# PHP - Format string

Tags: php, string, string-formatting

I have problems when trying to print on screen this string:

```
[(E/X)^x]^2
```

I'm not able to render it correctly here too, but `(E/X)` should be elevated to `x`, and then everything to `2`.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I try to explain myself better. I have `$colHeaders`, which is an array of array used to give data to a table. In the second child array, `title` field, is the string I want to render as I asked in the question.
The string must be formatted.

```
    $colHeaders = array(
                array(
                    'title' => $this->translator->trans('price'),
                    'rowspan' => 2,
                    'colspan' => 0
                ),
                array(
                    'title' => '[(E/X)^x]^ 2',
                    'rowspan' => 0,
                    'colspan' => 2
                ),
    );
```

Comment: Is this a string or a mathematic operation ? Could you post your **actual** code ?

Comment: the question is vague, please elaborate on it

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to output, and how it is different from what's outputted at the moment. Also, why don't you use `(E/X)^2x` ? It's the same but much more readable

Comment: @roberto06 I want the string formatted on the screen. (E/X) elevated to 2, and then everything to x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PHP, it's a simple HTML formatting using the  tag. Basically the output you want is:

```html
 [(E/X)<sup>x</sup>]<sup>2</sup>
```

In PHP, you just need to echo that, as such:

```
echo '[(E/X)<sup>x</sup>]<sup>2</sup>';
```

Comment: It's not `'title' => ' [(E/X)<sup>x</sup>]<sup>2</sup>'` giving you what you need?